# Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-1)(z-2)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

I am trying to find the Laurent series of the function $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-1)(z-2)}$$in the rings: 1) $0<|z-1|<1$, 2) $1<|z-1|$, 3) $1<|z-2|<2 $

First I expressed $f$ as $$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2z}-\dfrac{1}{z-1}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{z-2}$$

In 1), we have $$-\dfrac{1}{z-1}=-1\dfrac{1}{z-1},$$ $$\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{z-2}=\dfrac{-1}{2}(\dfrac{1}{1-(z-1)})$$$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{-1}{2}(z-1)^k$$

I don't know how to conveniently express $\dfrac{1}{2z}$

I had the same problem in 2) for $\dfrac{1}{2z}$ and in 3) for $\dfrac{1}{2z}$ and $\dfrac{-1}{z-1}$

I would appreciate suggestions to rearrange these terms so as to express them as geometric series. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{1+(z-1)}$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but how do I take that expression to a series? I mean, if I had $\dfrac{1}{1-(z-1)}$, for $|z-1|<1$, then I could take the expression to a geometric series. I don't see what to do with $\dfrac{1}{1+(z-1)}$

Comment: Small suggestion, try not to use `\dfrac`inline. `\frac` will suffice, especially in the title.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+w} = \frac{1}{1-(-w)} = \sum (-w)^n =  \sum (-1)^nw^n$

Comment: For |w|>1, $\frac{1}{1-w}=\frac{-1}{w}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{w}}$